# Troubleshooting CPU, PSU, MOBO, HW

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

Have a well aged PC that has started acting up. In short terms:

- It has worked fine for about 13 years.
- BIOS, Windows 10
- Started out with trouble booting.
- When pressing the ON button it sometimes start, other times not.
- Have to keep "trying" to start it over and over.

  - It sometimes is completely dead
  - Other times it start the fans for a fraction of a second, then goes dead.
  - Other times it goes into a loop; start for half a second, shut down, start for half a second, shut down etch until I unplug the power.
- Take out fans, HDDS, RAM, etc. and sometimes it starts other times not. Sometimes after powered off for a while, other times not etc.

There are some Red LED indicators on the motherboard; for CPU and RAM. Taking out the RAM usually put the PC in a state where it starts. Then put RAM back and boot. Sometimes the CPU led lights up, other times the RAM, but there is no pattern to it.

- Have run the extensive version of Microsoft memory test (9-12 hours) but it did not report anything.
- The voltages reported from the PSU internally using software are fine, but this could perhaps not tell all?
- The computer never crashes when running
- Only stage where there are troubles is at boot time.
- Have also run some CPU stress tests.

---

Any idea what could be going on here? The RAM test is fair enough, but are there other tests that can be run for e.g. the CPU, PSU, chips on the MB etc?

Not quite sure where to go from here. Thought of getting a new CPU (used) but no idea if it actually is the CPU ...

---

ASUS P7P55D: https://www.asus.com/supportonly/P7P55D/HelpDesk_Manual/

Comment: 13 years old? Could be [bad motherboard capacitors](https://www.google.com/search?q=bad+motherboard+capacitors).

Comment: Thanks all. For now, after all tests and work, it might seem like the ON button was at fault. Replaced it with a spare and at least for now, after 4-5 cold boots it all works fine. I still tag the suggested post as solution as it has an interesting flow chart. Did a visual inspection on capacitors as well.